# How can I show parents after child term inside a Views exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I have a vocabulary with states and cities, where city are children of state:

[image: Taxonomy]

I have an exposed filter with depth. How can I show parent term after child? For example, like this:

[image: Exposed filters]

I'm confused because the array has no relation between parent and child. For example, this is the form array select box:

```
{
#type: "select",
#options: {
0: {
option: {
17: "Aragon"
}
},
1: {
option: {
21: "-Barbastro"
}
},
2: {
option: {
20: "-Calatayud"
}
},
3: {
option: {
19: "-Zaragoza"
}
},
4: {
option: {
16: "Cataluña"
}
},
5: {
option: {
22: "-Barcelona"
}
},
6: {
option: {
24: "-Girona"
}
},
7: {
option: {
23: "-Tarragona"
}
},
8: {
option: {
18: "Valencia"
}
},
9: {
option: {
26: "-Alicante"
}
},
10: {
option: {
27: "-Elche"
}
},
11: {
option: {
25: "-Valencia"
}
},
All: "- Any -"
},
#size: "",
#default_value: "All"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exposed taxonomy filter select box form doesn't have any hierarchy built into the select form array (e.g. using subarray to present `optgroup` elements). Rather, its labels are indented to present the hierarchy on each select option.

To alter the labels, you can utilize `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter()` to alter the selectbox array structure with some string manipulate logic. For example:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $parent = '';
  $options = $form['tid']['#options'];
  foreach ($options as $index => $option) {
    if (is_object($option)) {
      $label = reset($option->option);
      $key = key($option->option);
      if (substr($label, 0, 1) != '-') {
        $parent = $label;
      }
      else {
        $options[$index]->option[$key] = $options[$index]->option[$key] . " ($parent)";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tank you so much! work perfect for me.